# Replace the contents of a github repository with the contents of a folder

Tags: linux, github

I'm trying to replace the contents of a github repository with the contents of a folder. I've tried `git push`, but it doesn't seem to do anything unless I add each of the files individually using the command line. Is there any command that I can use to replace the contents of the repository with the folder's contents?

My repository is here: https://github.com/jarble/downloadedModules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git add` adds your modified files to the queue to be committed later

The following are the steps to add a file and push to the repository:

```
git add <file/folder>
git commit -m "Checkin in code"
git push -u origin master
```

For detailed explanation refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143352/1268844)

Comment: How would I commit the folder's contents to a specific URL (like https://github.com/jarble/downloadedModules)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen `git add .` `git commit <etc.>` . The specific url you've pointed at - is the root of your repository - just run these commands _in_ the root of your local copy.

Comment: @AD7six I got the following error: `fatal: '..' is outside repository`

Comment: @AndersonGreen please read the answer and think a bit =)

Comment: @AD7six For the command `git commit <etc>`, I got the following error:  `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'`. What is `<etc>` supposed to represent here?

Comment: @Anshu I simply created a shell script with the contents `git add .
git commit -m "Checkin in code"
git push -u origin master`, and it worked as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @Anshu There's only one problem: this script doesn't remove the files that were removed from the local clone. How can I remove all of the files from the repository (without removing the repository's revision history)?

Comment: _git add -u_ would remove files which have been deleted

Comment: @Anshu Thanks, it worked as expected. Is it possible to do the reverse (replacing the contents of a folder with contents of the main branch)?