# Git commit commits staged and unstaged file

Tags: git

TL;DR: When one file has staged and unstaged changes, a commit will commit both versions, with the most recent changes to the file. Why? I thought a commit would only commit the staged version, as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19892657/279516.

Let's say we have one file in our working directory. (It has previously been committed to the repo.)

```
$ ls
foo.txt
```

The file's contents are currently just one character (the number 1):

```
$ cat foo.txt
1
```

Let's change the contents of the file to be "12". Now we have this:

```
$ cat foo.txt
12
```

Our working directory shows the change (instructional git output removed for brevity):

```
$ git status
modified:   foo.txt
```

Now a `git add` will add that file to the staging index.

```
$ git add foo.txt
```

You can't see it here, but the file name is now green, to indicate it has been staged:

```
$ git status
modified:   foo.txt
```

At this point, we could commit the file, and it would become part of our local repository. However, let's change `foo.txt` first and see what happens.

```
$ cat foo.txt
123
```

And if we check `git status` we see *two* versions of foo.txt:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:

        modified:   foo.txt

Changes not staged for commit:

        modified:   foo.txt
```

The first `foo.txt` is green. The second is red. The first one has as its contents "12". The second one has "123". What happens if we commit now? Only the staged `foo.txt` should be committed. So the `foo.txt` with "12" as its body will be in our local repo. The other version of `foo.txt` is still just in our working directory.

Commit `foo.txt` to our local repo, AS IT WAS WHEN WE ADDED IT:

```
$ git commit -m "Added 2 to foo." foo.txt
```

However, that's not what happened. Our working directory has no changes now. Both versions were committed. Why?

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to commit just the staged version, run `git commit` without specifying any files.

Example:

```
$ echo 2 > foo
$ git add foo
$ echo 3 > foo
$ git commit -m haha
```

Now the staged version is committed and the unstaged changes remain in your working directory. This can be easily verified:

```
$ git show HEAD:foo
2
$ git diff
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@ -1 +1 @@
-2
+3
```

---

Maybe let me demonstrate this behavior (`git commit` with file) with another example:

Perform these actions:

```
$ git init
$ echo 1 > foo
$ echo 1 > bar
$ git add foo bar
$ git commit -m 1
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` are committed

```
$ echo 2 > foo
$ echo 2 > bar
```

Now both are changed, let's stage `foo` and commit `bar`:

```
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m 2 bar
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
    modified: foo
$ git diff --name-only HEAD~ HEAD
bar
```

You see that `foo` is not changed in the commit, but the staged state is preserved.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the existing (correct) answers, it's worth noting that when using `git commit [flags] file1 file2 ... fileN`, you can put in the flags `--only` or `--include`:

- `--only` is the default, and it means *disregard what I staged so far, just make a commit with these files added*.
- `--include` means *to what I staged so far, add these files too*.

That's simple enough, but subtly wrong, because `--only` has to take an *after-commit* action as well.

A proper understanding of requires knowing what Git's *index* is and how `git commit` really, actually, commits what's *in the index*, not what's in the work-tree.

#### The way the Git programmers envision you using Git

The index is a fairly complicated thing, but *most* of it boils down to this: *The index holds the set of files that will go into your **next** commit.*  That is, if you run `git commit` right now—without listing any files—the *new* commit will be a *snapshot of all the files that are in the index right now, saving the contents that are in the index right now*.

What *this* means is that right after:

```
$ git clone <some-url>
$ cd <repository>
$ git checkout <branch>
```

you have, in your index, *all the same files, with the same content*, that you see in your work-tree.

That is, each commit is a complete snapshot of all the files in that commit, frozen forever, in a special, compressed, Git-only form.  This means you can always get back all of those files in their original form, by having Git extract and de-compress them, and that's what `git checkout` does: it finds the *latest* commit on the branch, and extracts and decompresses the files.  (This is oversimplified: `git checkout` is really quite fancy.  But that's the most basic thing it does.)

The useful-form files are in your *work-tree* where you can see them and work on them.  That's good, because the committed ones are frozen and Git-only, which obviously would be a problem. :-)

But, to make a *new* commit, rather than re-compressing all the work-tree files—which would take a long time in a lot of cases—what Git does is *save* the (unfrozen but still compressed and Git-only) files in this thing called, variously, the *index*, the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  So if you have `README.txt` and `main.py` in your work-tree, you also have them—in Git-only form—in your current commit (where they're frozen) **and** in your index (where they're thawed, but still Git-only).

Running `git add README.txt` tells Git to *overwrite* the index copy with the work-tree copy: take the ordinary format file and re-compress it to the Git-only format, replacing the `README.txt` in the index with the one from the work-tree.  It's not *frozen* yet—you can overwrite it again before you commit—but it's *ready* now.

Running `git commit`, without specifying any files, tells Git: *Package up whatever is in the index **right now** and make a new commit from that.*  This goes very fast since the files are already in the right form: Git just needs to freeze them into a new commit.  (Of course, until you make the files in the index *different* from the ones in the *current* commit, there's no point.)

Note that after `git commit` makes a *new* commit from the index, you're usually back to the normal situation where the index and the current commit match.  If you `git add`-ed all the files you changed, all *three* copies of each file—`HEAD`, index, and work-tree—match.

#### Introducing `--only` and `--include`

Running `git commit` *with* some files listed is a bit different, and this is where the `--only` vs `--include` come in.  If you use `--include`, Git essentially does `git add` on the listed files.  It's just shorthand for `git add <those files> && git commit`, more or less.

But, if you use `--only`—or don't specify, which *means* `--only`—what Git does is to shove the regular index out of the way and instead, make a new *temporary* index from whatever is in the frozen commit.  To this new temporary index, Git will `git add` each of the files you listed.  Then Git will make a new commit from this *other* index.  But now there's a problem, because Git now needs to go back to the normal index, and here's where it gets a bit tricky.

Having made a *new* commit from the temporary index, Git now needs to update the *real* index the same way.  In essence, after committing from the temporary index, Git re-adds the *same* set of files you listed to the *real* index, so that they match again.

Let's use the two-file example, with `README.txt` and `main.py`, again.  This time, let's add a version number after each file.  It's not part of the *name* of the file, it's just to help us remember:

```
    HEAD           index          work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(1)   README.txt(1)   README.txt(1)
main.py(1)      main.py(1)      main.py(1)
```

They start out with all three versions of each file being the same.  (Note that you *can't* change the `HEAD` copy.  You can only make a *new* commit, which then *becomes* the `HEAD` copy, because `HEAD` names the new commit.)

Now you edit both files in the work-tree:

```
    HEAD           index          work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(1)   README.txt(1)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(1)      main.py(2)
```

Let's say you now do `git add main.py` to copy the work-tree version into the index:

```
    HEAD           index          work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(1)   README.txt(1)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(2)      main.py(2)
```

If you run a plain `git commit` right now, the new `HEAD` would have the old `README.txt`, because the *index* has the old `README.txt`.  But instead, let's run `git commit --only README.txt`.  This makes a *temporary* index, so that we have:

```
    HEAD         temp-index       work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(1)   README.txt(2)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(1)      main.py(2)
```

Next, this makes a *new commit* from the temporary index:

```
    HEAD         temp-index       work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(2)   README.txt(2)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(1)      main.py(2)
```

Meanwhile, the *real* index is not yet changed.  Scroll up a bit and look at it: which version of `main.py` is in it?  Which version of `README.txt` is in it?

If Git merely switched back to the real index now, while keeping the commit you just made, this is what you'd have:

```
    HEAD         ugly-index       work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(2)   README.txt(1)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(2)      main.py(2)
```

That is, your work-tree is all the latest files.  Your *commit* has the updated `README.txt`.  But this ugly state means that the *next* commit will use the *old / wrong version* of `README.txt`!  So this is why Git now re-adds `README.txt` to the real index, so that you get:

```
    HEAD            index         work-tree
-------------   -------------   -------------
README.txt(2)   README.txt(2)   README.txt(2)
main.py(1)      main.py(2)      main.py(2)
```

Now you're ready to make a second commit with the updated `main.py` if you want.

Comment: Dang. Thanks for the info. That's more than I ever thought I'd need. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `git commit [...] foo.txt`:

> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit
>
> git commit [...] `[<file>…​]`
>
> `<file>…​`
> When files are given on the command line, the command commits the contents of the named files, without recording the changes already staged. The contents of these files are also staged for the next commit on top of what have been staged before.

Comment: So the default behavior then is to commit even unstaged changes? If that's the case, why bother doing a `git add`? And how would you commit just the staged version?

Comment: @BobHorn To commit just the staged version, run `git commit` without specifying any files.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thank you.