# Why add and commit in git?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

I'm new with [git](/questions/tagged/git) and I ask me why I have to use '`git add`' and '`git commit`' to commit a file into my repository.

---

With all IDEs I tried it is just one click to commit a file. This means the IDE combines 'add' and 'commit', right?!

And so I can't find any reason why it made sense to program both commands.

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69178/197871

Comment: @Chris could have probably left my comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143285/git-add-vs-push-vs-commit it's also a useful resource, especially the accepted answer

Comment: One example where it is useful it's when you want to commit only a part of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes can spread over multiple files, and you bundle all those changes in a single commit, with a clear title of what you've done.

For example in web development when you're done creating a new page you've probably changed multiple files.
Your commit message could be: `Add index page`
wich contains files:

- index.html
- script.js
- ...

After pushing this to remote the next person that pulls will get a somewhat finished index page, instead of just a single file.

Comment: You commit neither files nor changes but snapshots of the entire repo tree. Not to nit-pick, I'm OK with the general sense of your answer, but the first sentence *could* be misleading to some people.

Comment: Totally agree, reading back over it sounds misleading indeed

Answer (score 0):

> There are subtle differences between [git](/questions/tagged/git) and other cloud-based /
>   [svn](/questions/tagged/svn) repository systems.   One of which is the fact [git](/questions/tagged/git) has
>   a so-called "`staging area`".

**`git add`**

- In [git](/questions/tagged/git) before a file is updated in your repository, at first it's added to a so called `staging area`.
  This is done exactly, as the name of the function would suggest, via the **`git add`** command.
- During the *staging stage*, you tell your [git](/questions/tagged/git) which files you want to update. 
  This also means,  you can remove certain updates in staging area, if you change your mind about them.

---

**`git commit`**

- Once you produce a version, that you think is ready to be posted into a repository, you can commit the changes so you and others can see them.
- Once again, command named derivated from the action described, so in this case it would be **`git commit`** which commits the changes you have proposed in your staging area *(via `git add`)*.

---

So the difference is, if you use internet browser to upload files directly into a repository, you essentially skip the `git add` stage and you do `git commit` the files do the repository straight away.

Now, if you have a `git` project you manage only yourself, then yeah, `git add` is essentially useless for you. However, on a large project where you've got multiple people working, you want to make sure you don't over-write people's code, or just want to make sure you do properly version-manage, it is essential to properly utilize the staging area.

One of main advantages are, that during the commit phase, you don't usually commit a single file, however multiple changes, which makes it easier to keep track of who did what, rather than looking up every single file one by one.

> For more info *(not only on)* `git add` and `git commit` I would thoroughly recommend studying [this guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes). At least personally speaking, I became fluent in [git](/questions/tagged/git) from this resource alone

Answer (score 0):

The index in git is like a preflight area, a place where you can prepare the contents of the next commit.

You *can* basically ignore its existence if you use certain IDEs or if you commit with `-a` all the time. Some people do. In the simplest contexts, it's probably not a bad option.

However, as complexity grows, it'll become harder and harder not to interact more efficiently with it, which starts with a better understanding.

More details here :

[What does the git index contain EXACTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-contain-exactly)

and maybe there?

[Understanding git - Index](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-git-index-4821a0765cf)